# How to display highchart series line marker symbol from tooltip formatter?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, linegraph

By default highcharts display the line marker symbol in the tooltip.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sashi799/vsyfmu77/

Using tooltip formatter how can we add the line marker symbol?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.x+'<br/>'+this.series.name+': '+this.y;
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sashi799/zrhaokrn/

I want to add the circle symbol in front of the series name from formatter like it is in default scenario.

Answer (score 43):

I'm posting my own answer here as [Kacper Madej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25976671/1317805) here doesn't really answer the question at all, it simply places the 5 different symbols Highcharts uses in the same tooltip:

[image: Other Answer Demo]

This answer does work if we're using multiple colours, but it'd fail completely if all our series had the same colour - you may as well not display them at all.

---

## Pulling the relevant symbol into our tooltip

[image: Example Tooltip] [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/vrxLgxm0/)

Highcharts exposes a `symbolName` property within its `graphic` object which is a property itself on the `point` object itself. The shapes it uses are:

1. `"circle"` ●
2. `"diamond"` ♦
3. `"square"` ■
4. `"triangle"` ▲
5. `"triangle-down"` ▼

With this information, we can construct a `switch` statement within our `tooltip.formatter()` function which maps the relevant symbol with the symbol name that Highcharts exposes:

```
var symbol;

switch ( this.point.graphic.symbolName ) {
    case 'circle':
        symbol = '●';
        break;
    case 'diamond':
        symbol = '♦';
        break;
    case 'square':
        symbol = '■';
        break;
    case 'triangle':
        symbol = '▲';
        break;
    case 'triangle-down':
        symbol = '▼';
        break;
}
```

We can then place the symbol within our tooltip by referencing our `symbol` variable:

```
return this.x + '<br/>' + symbol + ' ' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y;
```

### Adding colour

[image: Coloured Symbol] [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/vrxLgxm0/1/)

We can then extend this to colour in our point to match the colour of the series. This simply involves wrapping our `symbol` in a `<span>` element, and giving it a `style` set to the colour of the series, which Highcharts gives us through `this.series.color`:

```
'<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + symbol + '</span>';
```

### Ensuring the symbol exists

Before putting this into production, however, you should be aware that sometimes a tooltip will appear for a point which has neither a `graphic` object or a `symbolName` property at all. This can occur when a point exists outside of the visible bounds of our chart - a tooltip will appear when hovering over the line, but the point itself isn't visible so has no need for any graphical-related properties.

To prevent JavaScript errors, we need to wrap our `switch` statement in the following `if` clause:

```
if ( this.point.graphic && this.point.graphic.symbolName )
```

With this, you'd also want to initially define your `symbol` variable as an empty string (`''`) so that it doesn't display as *undefined* in our tooltip:

```
var symbol = '';
```

---

## Handling custom marker images

[image: Image Marker Example] [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/vrxLgxm0/2/)

*For this example I've used the following image: [image: Example Image Marker]*

It's worth noting that whilst this solution works fine for this question, it will fall down when dealing with custom marker images - when these are used, there is no `graphic` object or `symbolName` property, and as we're using our own image we wouldn't want to display any of the shapes above anyway.

The first thing to do is tell Highcharts that we want to use HTML within our tooltip. We can do this by specifying `useHTML: true` on our `tooltip` object:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() { ... },
    useHTML: true
}
```

Fortunately, Highcharts tooltips support the HTML `<img />` element and allow us to pull the custom image URL through the `symbol` property within the `marker` object using `this.point.marker.symbol`.

```
this.point.marker.symbol
-> "url(http://i.imgur.com/UZHiQFQ.png)"
```

The second hurdle is removing the `url(` and `)` surrounding the actual image URL. For this we can use a regular expression to match the bits we want to remove. The regular expression I've gone with is `/^url\(|\)$/g`, which is visualised as:

[image: Regexper Example]

The `g` at the end states that we want to pull any matches, so we can replace both `url(` and `)` in one foul swoop:

```
var url = this.point.marker.symbol.replace(/^url\(|\)$/g, '');
-> "http://i.imgur.com/UZHiQFQ.png"
```

We can then place this into our `<img />` element, and store that in our `symbol` variable:

```
symbol = '<img src="' + url + '" alt="Marker" />';
```

*Finally* we want to ensure that the `marker` object and `symbol` property exist. I've chosen to do this as an `else if` on top of the original `if` statement declared in the *Ensuring the symbol exists* part above:

```
if ( this.point.graphic && this.point.graphic.symbolName ) { ) { ... }
else if ( this.point.marker && this.point.marker.symbol ) { ... }
```

Comment: This very well explained and also add new functionality to tooltip, because by default tooltip shows only colored circle ● Good job! :)

Comment: I get a Javascript error if I use this.point.graphic.symbolName within the pointFormatter function, I found that this.graphic.symbolName works though.
Otherwise, you saved my day, thanks a lot.

Comment: This was quite helpful. I also found it useful to know the _available_ symbols programmatically rather than assuming/hard-coding. Perhaps this is helpful to someone else: `Highcharts.getOptions().symbols`.

Answer (score 6):

I can see this is an older thread, but since the Highcharts API appears to differ on some points since the original post I'm providing an update here with the details that just worked for me in case this is helpful to others...

I'm using Highcharts JS v4.2.6 (2016-08-02) (along with highcharts-ng 0.0.12) and wasn't able to access the `this.point.graphic.symbolName` property to implement [James Donnelly's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317805/james-donnelly) solution -- instead I had to modify it to access `this.series.symbol`.

**The symbols that appear in the switch statement are being rendered from their [UTF-8 Geometric Shapes codes](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp) so it is necessary to structure the switch statements in the following fashion `symbol = 'charactercodegoeshere';`.** (ex: symbol = '&#9679'; in the case of the circle character)

The following code ultimately rendered the correct symbol in the correct color in the chart's tooltip for a given series:

```
tooltip: {
    style: {
        padding: 10,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function () {

        var symbol;

        switch ( this.series.symbol ) {
            case 'circle':
                symbol = '&#9679';
                break;
            case 'diamond':
                symbol = '&#9670';
                break;
            case 'square':
                symbol = '&#9632';
                break;
            case 'triangle':
                symbol = '&#9650';
                break;
            case 'triangle-down':
                symbol = '&#9660';
                break;
        }

        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %Y', this.x) + '<br/>' + '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '; font-size: 1.5em;">' + symbol + '</span> ' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y;
    }
}
```

The Highcharts.dateFormat() method was used to format epoch-millisecond timestamps for display.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fspzj4xw/

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';

                $.each(this.points, function () {
                    s += '<br/>' + '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '"> ●♦▲▼■ </span>' + ' ' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + 'm';
                });

                return s;
            },
            shared: true
        },
```

Comment: I think Kacper's intention is just to show some of the symbols that could be used, and it is up to the coder to pick one and delete the ones not required.

Answer (score 4):

A lightweight solution would be to hook up to the Series `afterInit` event and add the symbols:

```
Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Series, 'afterInit', function() {
    this.symbolUnicode = {
        circle: '●',
        diamond: '♦',
        square: '■',
        triangle: '▲',
        'triangle-down': '▼'
    }[this.symbol] || '●';
});
```

View live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pjqz79pv/1/

Comment: Hello Sir Torstein Honsi can you help me in this problem ?? 
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618957/multiple-events-drilldown-function-e