# How to get series marker symbol when displaying shared tooltips?

Tags: highcharts

Link to JSFiddle with question content marked by comments: https://jsfiddle.net/z1q7aqo3/
Specifically, the part which needs filling in is

```
'tooltip': {
    'formatter': function(){
        var output = '<strong>' + this.y + '</strong>';
        var sorted = this.points.sort(function(a, b){
            if (a.y == b.y){
                 return 0;
            }
            return a.y < b.y ? 1 : -1;
        });

        sorted.forEach(function(point, index){
            var marker = '';
            /* 
                TODO: How do I determine what symbol is used for the marker?
            */
            output += '<br /><span style="color: ' + point.series.color + '">' + marker + '</span> ' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y;
        });
        return output;
    },
    'shared': true
}
```

I have a line chart with a number of series. On mouseover, the tooltip displays all the values of all of them, in sorted order. This part is done and can be seen in the JSFiddle. My question is, I want each the text for each series in the tooltip to include the marker symbol used for that series, styled in the color of the series. The color styling is also complete and can be seen in the JSFiddle, but how do I get the marker symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Modifying form earlier Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29558231/3898339) it is for individual series tooltip. Here modified to shared tooltip

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/xw949owv/) demo

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  'title': {
    'text': 'Random Chart'
  },
  'tooltip': {
    'formatter': function(){
        var output = '<strong>' + this.y + '</strong>';
      var sorted = this.points.sort(function(a, b){
        if (a.y == b.y){
            return 0;
                }
        return a.y < b.y ? 1 : -1;
            });

      sorted.forEach(function(point, index){
        var marker = '';

                if ( point.point.graphic && point.point.graphic.symbolName ) {
                    switch ( point.point.graphic.symbolName ) {
                        case 'circle':
                            marker = '●';
                            break;
                        case 'diamond':
                            marker = '♦';
                            break;
                        case 'square':
                            marker = '■';
                            break;
                        case 'triangle':
                            marker = '▲';
                            break;
                        case 'triangle-down':
                            marker = '▼';
                            break;
                    }
                }
        /* 
            TODO: How do I determine what symbol is used for the marker?
        */
        output += '<br /><span style="color: ' + point.series.color + '">' + marker + '</span> ' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y;
      });
      return output;
        },
    'shared': true
    },
  'series': [{
    'name': 'Series 1', 
    'data': [1, 3, 7, 19, 11, 27, 8, 15]
  }, {
    'name': 'Series 2', 
    'data': [2, 1, 8, 12, 14, 20, 9, 10]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Oh it's point.point! No wonder I couldn't get the graphic data, I was using point alone haha. Thanks!

Comment: An addendum to it though, if I disable markers so that now the marker only appears as a result of the shared tooltip, point.point.graphics is no longer set. How then would I retrieve the marker symbol?